# Impact of Facebook API integration on app file size

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Does anyone know, or can give me an idea, of how much file size adding the Facebook Install App SDK contributes to an iOS app. I'm having overall mobile app file size issues with my developers, and they are telling me that adding the 'Install App' API from Facebook added substantial weight to the overall file size of my iOS app. I am finding that difficult to understand because it would be in Facebook's interest to keep the file size of integration to mobile apps quite low.

Hoping someone can help me. (Sorry but I don't have a technology background so I hope this makes sense.)

Kind regards,
Farida

Comment: It is very very tiny. What are you developers saying?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for getting back to me. The developers haven't given me a actual figure but they said the impact is 'significant'. The SDK I asked them to add is the one that allows me to do the 'Install App' ads. What they are saying doesn't make sense to me as I assume FB would be very careful about how much file size they are adding to an app. Do you have or know of an expected range of file size impact that I can share with the developers? I would really appreciate it! Thanks again

Comment: I don't have exact numbers but yes we have done a bunch of work to make it as small as possible